# Fluent Interface(chaining method) with C++ parallelism

Tags: c++, design-patterns, simd, fluent-interface

Does anyone have an experience in using Fluent Interface (or chaining method) with SIMD and other levels of parallelism using C++? Is there any performance penalty, side effects, e.g. on instruction-level?

By chaining, we define an order to perform the methods, but how this order defines an argument calculations (**solution for this question was found** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37252328/c-execution-order-in-method-chaining))?

This technique is widely popular within web-developers. I have thought to apply it for my personal project for C++, but will I lose the performance cause of that?

I really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try it. Test it. Experiment. And *measure* and *benchmark*. That's really the only way to be sure.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, I agree with you. However, I was hoping someone had an experience (good or bad).

Comment: I think you should have posted a link to this Fluent stuff, because I have no idea what it is (as mostly C++ and partly JS coder).