# How do char arrays and their pointers work in c++ exactly?

Tags: c++

I am a beginner student in c++ and there is one thing I cannot understand when working with character arrays: So, I know that pointers are essentially variables that "point" to the memory address of another variable, and that the name of an array(Ex: int a[20]) is a constant pointer to the values in that array. When working with different numeric types(int, float etc.) if we output through a message the name of that array it shows the address of the first element, but if we do the same with a char type, it doesn't show the address, but the value of the variable. 
    Example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{int a[]={1,2,3,4,5};
cout<<a<<endl; //through output, it shows the memory address of the first 
element of the array;
char b[]={"Mountain"};
cout<<b; //It outputs the word "Mountain"
    return 0;
}
```

Is the pointer from a char array automatically converted to its value when you output it?

Comment: OT: As a quote: " beginner student in c++" you shouldn't study these types of arrays.  Study `std::vector`, `std::array` and `std::string` instead. If you are going to write real C++ you ain't gonna need the old C-style array anyway.

Comment: The question as presented in the title is way too broad. If you want to ask why printing a char array works differently from printing an int array, a good title for your question would be "why does printing a char array work differently from printing an int array?"

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference. `char` pointers aren't somehow magically different than `int` pointers. So what's going on, than?

`std::cout <<` (or the older `printf()`) have overloads for `char*`. Meaning that the functions behave differently if the input is a `char*`: the pointer is iterated until a `'\0'` character is reached (see [null terminated string](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/181505/what-is-a-null-terminated-string)).

---

```
char b[]={"Mountain"};
```

`b` does **not** contain

- `{'M', 'o', 'u', 'n', 't', 'a', 'i', 'n'}`

but instead

- `{'M', 'o', 'u', 'n', 't', 'a', 'i', 'n', '\0'}` **<- `'\0'`**

making the iterating and stopping possible.

This also explains why the array size of `b` is `1` larger than the number of characters inside the word.

[image]

---

To add, you should **not** use these char pointers. They are dangerous and are long replaced by modern utilites like [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

---

now  `int a[]={1,2,3,4,5};`  is OK but `std::array<int, 5> a = {1,2,3,4,5};` is even better.

- the types are unique (`std::array<int, 4> != std::array<int, 5>`)
- it has a `.size()` function.
- you can therefore pass it to other functions without having to add a size argument
- it's as fast as a normal array

[`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) can be used by including `<array>`.

---

If you ever go for something like `int* a = new int[5];` than stop right there and instead use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

---

Fianally never ever say `use namespace std;` ([here why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice))

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to respond to my question. I know it sounded silly, but I guess curiosity sometimes mixes with dumb! Could you please link me an alternative to different functions for strings that I can use that were previously available in C? (Like strtok,strcpy,strstr etc.)

Comment: for `strcpy` you simply say `std::string a = std::string b;` - [`std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) allows you to do alot of the other things (mostly not 1 line, though) like explained on [`strtok`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289347/using-strtok-with-a-stdstring) and also `strstr`. The best string manipulation gives you [`std::regex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) (which relies on `std::string`). In the end you can also always call `.c_str()` on a `std::string` to get the raw C-Style string.

Comment: for simple replacing, finding `std::string` has `.replace()` and `.find()`. This *could* even be chained as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27158812/does-this-code-from-the-c-programming-language-4th-edition-section-36-3-6-ha) post the questions example displays that. Though with care.

Comment: @mountainkingRune Your question is still listed as unanswered. Doesn't Dannys answer answer your question? If it does, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how you interpret the parameters. cout << operator will consider (sometype*) as an address, but particularly char* as a string.

If you write a function taking your own parameters, you can interpret what ever the way you like.

In this problem, if you want to get the address, you can do it so

```
std::cout << static_cast<const void*>(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

In C, strings are represented as a pointer to `char`. for this reason, when you pass a `char*` to an `ostream` (such as `std::cout`) in C++, it will interpret it as a null-terminated string and print that string's content rather than the address. If you want to print the address, you'll have to cast that pointer to a different kind:

```
std::cout << (void*)b;
```

Answer (score 0):

`cout` is an output stream. When we use output streams, and pass a `char*`, it treats it as a null terminated string (i.e. it prints all the characters till it find '\0') in the string. For any other pointer type, the address is printed.